# Shelah's "Can you take Solovay's inaccessible away?"

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, large-cardinals, descriptive-set-theory

I was wandering if there was a book, thesis or some notes where Shelah's argument for

1. $\mathtt{ZF}+\mathtt{DC}+$"All sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable" is equiconsistent with $\mathtt{ZFC} + \exists \kappa$ inaccessible
2. $\mathtt{ZF}+\mathtt{DC}+$"All sets of reals have the Baire property" is equiconsistent with $\mathtt{ZFC}$

contained in [Can you take Solovay's inaccessible away?](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02760522) is explained in a newer and/or "more digestible" way. Is there?

Thanks!

Comment: [Raisonnier's follow-up paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02760523) addressing 1 may be of interest.

Comment: There's a chapter titled The Raisonnier Filter in Ralf Schindler's textbook (Set Theory: Exploring Independence and Truth). It presents the Lebesgue measure result in a learner-friendly manner, I think.

Comment: You may look at Ralf Schindler's book on set theory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chapter 9.5 of the book by Bartoszynski-Judah presents Raisonnier's proof (answering your question 1):

Assume that $\aleph_1$ is not inaccessible in $L$, hence a successor in $L$.  So there is a real $x$ which knows that the $L$-predecessor is countable, hence $\aleph_1^{L[x]}=\aleph_1$, so $X:=\mathbb R \cap L[x]$ is uncountable.

Now assume that  all $\Sigma^1_2(x)$-sets are Lebesgue measurable. Then (this needs some work) the "Raisonier filter" $F_X$ built from $X$, which is a $\bf \Sigma^1_3$-set, is a rapid filter and therefore (again some work, known earlier) not measurable.