# Follow up question: Shelah's "Can you take Solovay's inaccessible away?"

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, descriptive-set-theory

In [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/420867) to the question " [Shelah's "Can you take Solovay's inaccessible away?"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420839/shelahs-can-you-take-solovays-inaccessible-away) " the following is stated:

> Assume that $\aleph_1$ is not inaccessible in $L$, hence a successor in $L$.  So there is a real $x$ which knows that the $L$-predecessor is countable, hence $\aleph_1^{L[x]}=\aleph_1$, so $X:=\mathbb R \cap L[x]$ is uncountable.

I  understand why $\aleph_1^{L[x]}=\aleph_1$ but I don't know how we can deduce that the intersection is uncountable.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In any model of ZF, there is a surjection from the reals onto $\omega_1$. So if the $\omega_1$ of $L[x]$ (i.e., $(\omega_1)^{L[x]}$) is uncountable, there is a surjection from the reals of $L[x]$ (i.e., $\mathbb R\cap L[x]$) onto $(\omega_1)^{L[x]}$, which means the reals of $L[x]$ themselves form an uncountable set.

In fact, in this particular case, we have $|\mathbb R \cap L[x]| = |(\omega_1)^{L[x]}|$ by the relativization of Gödel's theorem that the continuum hypothesis holds in $L$. Gödel's result may be restated in symbols as $L[x]\vDash |\mathbb R| = |\omega_1|$, which amounts to the fact that there is a bijection witnessing that $|\mathbb R \cap L[x] | = |(\omega_1)^{L[x]}|$ that is in $L[x]$.

In general, though, the argument from the first paragraph shows that if $M$ is an inner model and $(\omega_1)^M$ is uncountable, then $M$ contains uncountably many real numbers, regardless of whether $M$ satisfies the continuum hypothesis or even the Axiom of Choice.

Answer (score 9):

Gabe Goldberg has already given a couple of proofs, but here's another one, just because I like it.  Being a model of ZFC, $L[x]$ sees a one-to-one map of its $\omega_1$ into its reals. That map, in the real world, maps $\omega_1={\omega_1}^{L[x]}$ one-to-one into the reals of $L[x]$.

(Both occurrences of "into" above could be upgraded to "onto", since $L[x]$ also satisfies CH. But the upgrade isn't needed, so I don't care about CH.)